# Is it possible to suspend PHP script until a response from a remote server arrives?

Tags: php, curl

I have a script that relies on a **curl** response from a remote server. On my current shared hosting, this takes around **300 ms** for the response to arrive. I'm in the middle of a migration to VPS in a more suitable location so I expect the delay to drop significantly, but still not negligibly since the server is being built to act as an API, serving high amount of clients.

As of now, if I understand the mechanism correctly, those **300 ms** waiting for a response, are 300 ms the server could be serving other requests. With the rest of the script taking only **3 ms** to complete, this is potential 100 requests that couldn't be served. Less, after the migration, but every such request will block high amount of potential requests that could be served while the script was merely waiting for the response.

So my question is, is there a way to suspend the script until the response arrives, making the process manager available to serve other requests in the meantime?

I only found out about **sleep()** and **usleep()** which is of no use to me, because I will never know how long it takes for the response to arrive.

Comment: You could run the call asynchronously and cache it, but as a usual webserver is able to process multiple requests, "this is potential 100 requests that couldn't be served" is a wrong assumption

Comment: Also, what makes you think that a migration of your own code to another server speeds up the execution of that cURL request?

Comment: @Nilesh how does that other question relate to this one?

Comment: This is an incorrect assumption about how web server's deal with simultaneous requests. This is a good article explaining request handling and concurrency with PHP ~ https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-concurrency

Comment: @NicoHaase But technically it is true. The child process executing the script cannot process another request while still in the middle of execution. In other words, if all available children are occupied waiting for a response to this script, they all are missing on potentially 100 requests a children.

Comment: @NicoHaase The migration to VPS will speed up the execution time, because the latency between the servers is shorter. In other words, my current shared hosting has a terrible latency which I will reduce moving to a VPS with guaranteed resource, on a datacenter in a location closer to the remote server.

Comment: 300ms for a external API request is not that much, but 3ms to run a whole PHP script is. Did you try to use caching?

Answer (score 1):

> As of now, if I understand the mechanism correctly, those 300 ms waiting for a response, are 300 ms the server could be serving other requests.

This isn't quite true. There are 300ms where *that thread* cannot process another request, but the server itself will be running many threads. This is **parallel concurrency**.

In fact, it will be running many more threads than it has CPU cores, and actually *relying* on delays such as this to efficiently schedule them. It's not unusual to have 100 active server threads on a server with 2 or 4 cores; at any given moment, at least 96 of those can't use the CPU, but that's generally fine because they're waiting for other things.

This only becomes a problem when *every* request has such significant waits that all the server's threads are waiting *at the same time*. For instance, if you get 1 request per millisecond which all need this slow response, and set a limit of 100 threads, then after 100 ms all the threads will be waiting, and your CPU will be idle for 200 ms until the first one wakes up.

The alternative approach is **asynchronous concurrency**. In that approach, the application itself manages a queue of events, and can start handling a new incoming request while it waits for the slow response.

A popular example of this approach is node.js. Commonly, you would run one node.js thread per CPU core, and that thread would be responsible for handling as many requests "at once" as possible.

There are a number of frameworks that allow this approach with PHP, such as [ReactPHP](https://reactphp.org/), [AmPHP](https://amphp.org/), and [OpenSwoole](https://openswoole.com/). Depending on how you've written your code, you may need to make substantial changes for it to work correctly, so would need to consider how much benefit you expect in practice.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword you're looking for is async (Asynchronous) functionality which is available in PHP but with a [small detour](https://github.com/spatie/async). With this, you dont need to wait or sleep it does so automatically without consuming your CPU cycles but not as effectively as other langauges as this is achieved in house as in, just another software layer.

PHP is build on `http`, 1 request 1 fast answer. The more the ping, the longer it takes and this is quickly noticeable high volume scenarios but back then we didn't have 64 core CPU's back than.

Each language has their own strenghts and in this explicit example you will find that its much more difficult to do this in PHP than other languages.

If you're only polling to an API, might I suggest Node instead? It has that functionality build in.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will look into it. I was avoiding Node simply because I am familiar with PHP and already have the API worked out to a certain degree.